# Big Bang as stretching space time?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang, cosmological-constant

I am still new to researching the big bang so please be patient. I am having trouble envisioning the expansion. As I understand under current theory it is not to be thought of as a singularity expanding as an explosion as it doesn't expand into anything it expands everywhere at once. However the same current theory explains the universe as beginning infinitely small and expanding rapidly.

Would it be appropriate to imagine the big bang as folded space time expanding out in roughly the same manner as a folded piece of paper flattens?

This also leads to another question why is it theorised that the entire universe is expanding into nothing rather than an expansion of everything else (e.g matter) into a pre-existing possibly infinite empty vacuum space? Is this in conflict with Einstein's theory of relativity?

I would also appreciate suggestions for further study.

Comment: Do [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)#Detail) [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker_metric#General_metric) help?

Comment: Does [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) help?